# selenium if element not found = nan

Tags: python, selenium

I didn't want to bring up an old thread here but I'm having an issue with

```
try:
    mainimg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/img").get_attribute("src")
    img1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/img").get_attribute("src")
    img2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/img").get_attribute("src")
    img3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/img").get_attribute("src")
    img4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/img").get_attribute("src")
    img5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div/img").get_attribute("src")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("couldnt find images")
```

this works fine.

However.

When I'm compressing the info the a csv,
It will cause an error saying I can't find img3.
It should be passed because of `NoSuchElementException.`

Is there a way I can change the above code to allow 
elements that are not found as `NAN`

Comment: What info are you compressing into a csv?

Comment: Everything you see there

mainimg
img1
img2
img3
img4
img5

How ever not every page has 5 images some only have 1 or 2

Comment: is it possible to set
Not defined to = NaN
Or error?

Having a nan in my output is better then the script stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if element which you are looking exist. You can try this solution:

```
img3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'has-post-thumbnail')]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/img")
if len(img3) > 0
    img3 = img3.get_attribute("src")
```